# Follow instagram page through Facebook graph api

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I have already using https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/pageid/relationship?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
API for following an Instagram page but now it is not working.
I know its required relationship level scope but on Instagram dev panel it says.
*"We no longer offer additional permissions to new applications using the legacy API".*
I searched for the API on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference but not found any relationship API. I have attached my Instagram account with a Facebook page by following the steps in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started/.
Now how we can follow an Instagram page by using Facebook graph API.

Comment: no longer supported, you cannot follow users

Comment: @krisrak there is any official document link, can you share here.

Comment: you have the official links in questions, old API they are not approving, new API does not have that endpoint, so no longer supported